# Which password hashing algorithm is platform and language independent?

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords, password-encryption

I am working on a SCADA application which has applications developed in Java,C# and C++ and runs on Windows, Linux, AIX currently. I want to adopt password hashing to store it in database securely. Which algorithm has capability to support all these requirements? Are there libraries available for the same?

Comment: As far as I know every well-known password hashing *algorithm* is both platform and language independent. Argon2 seems to be state of the art, but older algorithms such as bcrypt or pbkdf2 may have better support. Library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Just as James said, but if you're thinking about this from a runtime perspective, then there are caveats. Let's take Java. There exists a JVM for any platform out there and possibly multiple per platform, but they are not strictly compatible in terms of supported algorithms. They might have different Cryptographic Providers which implement different algorithms or variants of algorithms. If you want to be sure, don't use the algorithms from the standard library and instead use an additional library.